# Jasmine unit test: this.wvInstance.docViewer.getDocument is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm testing a method which has the following call in my component:

```
createBar() {
    const pageWidth = this.wvInstance.docViewer.getDocument();
}
```

I'm attempting to mock the entirety of this call. `getDocument()` returns a `CoreControls.Document`, which just consists of two strings.

`mockViewerInstance` in the `beforeEach()`:

```
mockWebViewerInstance = jasmine.createSpyObj('WebViwerInstance', {
  docViewer: {
    getDocument: function() : CoreControls.Document {
      return new CoreControls.Document('', '');
    }
  }
});
```

Test:

```
  it('should create the nav bar', () => {
    component.wvInstance = mockWebViewerInstance;
    component.createBar();
  });
```

I keep getting an error: `TypeError: this.wvInstance.docViewer.getDocument is not a function`. Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 component.wvInstance = {docViewer: {getDocument: jasmine.createSpy('getDocument')}};
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember also having problems creating spies for property values. Which jasmine version are you using?
There is this [issue](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1442) about creating spies with properties. Since version 3.5 you should be able to use

```
mockWebViewerInstance = jasmine.createSpyObj('WebViwerInstance', {}, {
  docViewer: {
    getDocument: function() : CoreControls.Document {
      return new CoreControls.Document('', '');
    }
  }
});
```

If using version < 3.5, then you probably have to use `spyOnPropery()` as a separate statement.